# R - find all unique values among subsets of a data frame

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I have a data frame with two columns. The first column defines subsets of the data.  I want to find all values in the second column that only appear in one subset in the first column.

For example, from:

```
df=data.frame(
  data_subsets=rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=5),
  data_values=c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,6,7))

data_subsets data_values
      A           1
      A           2
      A           3
      A           4
      A           5
      B           2
      B           3
      B           4
      B           6
      B           7
```

I would want to extract the following data frame.

```
data_subsets   data_values
    A              1
    A              5
    B              6
    B              7
```

I have been playing around with `duplicated` but I just can't seem to make it work.  Any help is appreciated.  There are a number of topics tackling similar problems, I hope I didn't overlook the answer in my searches!

*EDIT*

I modified the approach from @Matthew Lundberg of counting the number of elements and extracting from the data frame.  For some reason his approach was not working with the data frame I had, so I came up with this, which is less elegant but gets the job done:

```
counts=rowSums(do.call("rbind",tapply(df$data_subsets,df$data_values,FUN=table)))
extract=names(counts)[counts==1]
df[match(extract,df$data_values),]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, find the count of each element in df$data_values:

```
 x <- sapply(df$data_values, function(x) sum(as.numeric(df$data_values == x)))

> x
 [1] 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1
```

Now extract the rows:

```
> df[x==1,]
   data_subsets data_values
1             A           1
5             A           5
9             B           6
10            B           7
```

Note that you missed "A 5" above.  There is no "B 5".

Comment: Great, thanks--edited above to reflect my mistake!  When applying to my own data set, I get the error "level sets of factors are different". Will investigate and report back..

Comment: Works for the example data set so upvote, but for some reason, wouldn't work for my real data set. See the edit up top to see my (inelegant) solution

Answer (score 2):

You had the right idea with `duplicated`. The trick is to combine `fromLast = TRUE` and `fromLast = FALSE` options to get a full list of non-duplicated rows.

```
!duplicated(df$data_values,fromLast = FALSE)&!duplicated(df$data_values,fromLast = TRUE)
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Indexing your data.frame with this vector gives:

```
df[!duplicated(df$data_values,fromLast = FALSE)&!duplicated(df$data_values,fromLast = TRUE),]
   data_subsets data_values
1             A           1
5             A           5
9             B           6
10            B           7
```

Comment: Thanks!  Seems to work well for the example data set but I had difficulties applying to my own data set. See my edit up top for my (inelegant) solution

Answer (score 0):

A variant of P Lapointe's answer would be

```
df[! df$data_values %in% df[duplicated( unique(df)$data_values ), ]$data_values,]
```

The `unique()` deals with the possibility (not in your test data) that some rows in the data may be identical and you want to keep them once if the same `data_values` does not appear for distinct `data_sets` (or distinct other columns).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'dplyr' and 'explore' library to overcome this problem.

```
library(dplyr)
library(explore)

df=data.frame(
  data_subsets=rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=5),
  data_values=c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,6,7))

df  %>% describe(data_subsets)

######## output ########
#variable = data_subsets
#type     = character
#na       = 0 of 10 (0%)
#unique   = 2
# A       = 5 (50%)
# B       = 5 (50%)
```