# Find unique 'item groups' in multivariate data

Tags: r, grouping, unique

I am trying to isolate the unique **groups of items** in my data - unique groupings of rows associated with a key column, not unique items, which is what most use the unique function for. The question takes some careful reading...so please be kind enough to digest the example first.

To be clear, **I do NOT want the unique subset of the group column, nor do I want unique subsets of items, nor even unique combinations of groups and items**. I know these have been covered elsewhere [unique() for more than one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790732/unique-for-more-than-one-variable).  What I want are **unique sets of items, where sets are defined by groups**.

Here is an example

```
set.seed(1234)
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(group = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),each = 4), 
item =  c(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 10, 12, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 3,
 5, 2, 10, 12, 1, 2), c = runif(8))
A <- A[-23, ] #so we can have an example of unbalanced groups
> A
    group item          c
 1:     A    1 0.15904600
 2:     A    2 0.03999592
 3:     A    4 0.21879954
 4:     A    3 0.81059855
 5:     B    5 0.52569755
 6:     B    2 0.91465817
 7:     B    3 0.83134505
 8:     B    6 0.04577026
 9:     C   10 0.15904600
10:     C   12 0.03999592
11:     C    1 0.21879954
12:     C    2 0.81059855
13:     D    1 0.52569755
14:     D    2 0.91465817
15:     D    4 0.83134505
16:     D    3 0.04577026
17:     E    6 0.15904600
18:     E    3 0.03999592
19:     E    5 0.21879954
20:     E    2 0.81059855
21:     F   10 0.52569755
22:     F   12 0.91465817
23:     F    2 0.04577026

#The unique groups are A:F, and the unique items are 1:6,10,12. 
#The unique sets of items are: # (set1) 1,2,3,4; (set2) 5,2,3,6; 
#(set3) 10,2,1,2; (set4) 10,12,2
```

I want to retrieve these unique sets of items (note again that the item sets are formed by groups).
(The third column means little at this time. For fun, I include sums by each 'item').
The output table should look like this:

```
group item c 
A 1 0.68474355 #note that groups A and D share this same set of items (set1) 
A 2 0.95465409
A 4 1.05014459# c sums groupAitem4$c with groupDitem4$c
A 3 0.85636881
B 5 0.74449709 # group E has the same items (set2), even if not the same order, c is totaled by item.
B 2 1.72525672
B 3 0.87134097
B 6 0.20481626
C 10 0.159046
C 12 0.03999592
C 1 0.21879954
C 2 0.81059855
F 10 0.52569755 #Not the same as group C
F 12 0.91465817
F 2 0.04577026
```

I suppose there might be a way of going through reshape that would be quite awkward. My data is large, so efficient procedures like `data.table` would be very appreciated.

Comment: Not fancy/efficient but `strsplit(unique(paste0(A$group,",",A$item)),",")`

Comment: How do you want to handle the various `A$c` values that belong to each unique pairing?  Take a look at `aggregate` and `plyr` for general ideas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique() for more than one variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790732/unique-for-more-than-one-variable) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944816/unique-on-a-dataframe-with-only-selected-columns?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873203/r-find-all-unique-values-among-subsets-of-a-data-frame?rq=1

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I can keep the first of the A$c columns, but that it the least of my worries.

Comment: @JessicaB: the strsplit... code you suggest does not seem to work. It gives me all the rows of A, duplicates and all. Note that what I want to keep are the unique combinations of items.

Comment: @DWin: I hope with the added notes, and with the example which had always been there, you now understand that my question is very different from the item you referenced. The other questions requested unique groups, I want unique groups of items.

Comment: The more I think of it, the more I realize that the unique function may not be up to this... other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: My answer shows you the 23 unique group/item combinations - I notice your example data.table 'A' has no duplicated group/item combinations so I clearly don't understand the question, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(plyr)  
my<-ddply(A,.(group),summarize, mylist=list(item))

> my
  group       mylist
1     A   1, 2, 4, 3
2     B   5, 2, 3, 6
3     C 10, 12, 1, 2
4     D   1, 2, 4, 3
5     E   6, 3, 5, 2
6     F    10, 12, 2

yy<-as.list(1:6) # used for `Map` function
my$mylist<-Map(function(x) sort(my$mylist[[x]]),yy) # sort the order of elements in list for matching

> my
  group       mylist
1     A   1, 2, 3, 4
2     B   2, 3, 5, 6
3     C 1, 2, 10, 12
4     D   1, 2, 3, 4
5     E   2, 3, 5, 6
6     F    2, 10, 12

myuni<-unique(my$mylist)

> myuni
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 5 6

[[3]]
[1]  1  2 10 12

[[4]]
[1]  2 10 12

finaloutput<-my[match(myuni,my$mylist),]
  group       mylist
1     A   1, 2, 3, 4
2     B   2, 3, 5, 6
3     C 1, 2, 10, 12
6     F    2, 10, 12

A[A$group %in% finaloutput$group,]
   group item           c
1      A    1 0.113703411
2      A    2 0.622299405
3      A    4 0.609274733
4      A    3 0.623379442
5      B    5 0.860915384
6      B    2 0.640310605
7      B    3 0.009495756
8      B    6 0.232550506
9      C   10 0.113703411
10     C   12 0.622299405
11     C    1 0.609274733
12     C    2 0.623379442
21     F   10 0.860915384
22     F   12 0.640310605
23     F    2 0.232550506
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but same issue as Jessica's proposal above. This answer gives 8 rows not 4. Duplicates of the item sets are included.

Comment: It would be helpful to demonstrate your solutions with the reproducible code.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. There is already the reproducible code.

Comment: Please be kind enough to compare the outputs of your reproducible code with the output I want, as clearly described in the question. You will see that they do not match. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Not really. I explained that I do not want unique sets of items. If you could indulge me and try the example with: A <- data.frame(group = rep(1:12, each=4), item=sample(letters,6), c = runif(8)). The results should include all items in a group that is selected as containing a unique set. Yours would not.

Comment: I am sorry. You said that you want to match the output?

Comment: I am sorry @Metrics. I will have to give up on trying to make you read and understand the question. It is not your garden-variety "unique" request. I would be grateful if you had taken the time to understand what I want. For now, I am convinced that is not case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36349/discussion-between-user2627717-and-metrics)

Comment: Sorry, I am not available. I suggest you to edit the question and make it more clear with the expected output. Otherwise, it is likely to be good candidate for the closure.

Comment: It's more clearer now. I think you can use unique item set as a list and then compare it. But, I am not sure whether your item set can be identified as a list in the real data.

Comment: The answer looks great. The only step missing is the conversion of the table back to the 'reshape-long' format. I am not sure that it is so straightforward with lists. Would you have a hint? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have the solution for that at this point. But, I will try. In the meantime, it will be good if you post that as a new question by making reference to this solution (and of course your question)

Comment: Thanks, but there is no way to get to the table I posted in the question without that step. It seems to be a critical element of the answer I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to combinations

```
unique(dataset[, c("group", "item")])
```

Comment: No dice. I tried to explain in the question that I want all unique sets of items, sets of items are defined by group. Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean to ask for unique 2-way combinations of items rather than "unique sets of items". Peoples' understanding of mathematical sets may be getting in the way of communication here.

Comment: @DWin. I think the example in the question shows that I do not want 2-way combinations. I thought some effort went into making sure that my question does not get mixed up that way... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use set.seed, or dput ,everyone trying to use your code will get a different result. This may give you what you want although at the moment it is unclear if the number of items in a groups will always be small and whether it is only the 2way combinations that are desired:

```
unique(t(do.call(cbind, tapply(A$item, A$group, combn, 2) ) )  )
```

The `combn` function returns the unique combinations in a column format so I needed to transpose before using `unique` which operates on rows by default. If you could work with a column oriented result you can skip that step if you use the MARGIN argument:

```
unique(do.call(cbind, tapply(A$item, A$group, combn, 2) )  , MARGIN=2)
```

Comment: If you are expecting to match with your output, you just need to use `A[unique(A$item),]`. See my answer

Comment: @Metrics: Please see my response to your answer.

Comment: @Metrics: I hope the example helps to explain what I want. I understand the question is tricky.